# Show Facebook Page Feed on Website

Tags: plugins

From my searches it looks like [Placid](https://github.com/alecritson/Placid) is the way to go for showing Facebook contenton the front-end of my website. What I'm completely confused about is how to get started. Does anyone have a simple step-by-step answer on how I connect Placid to my Facebook page?

Comment: First, you would need to create an app for your facebook page. You are also going to need a Facebook developer account: https://developers.facebook.com. Once your app is created and you have a Facebook developer account, I would recommend starting with the Facebook open graph explorer: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer. With the explorer, you can build/debug your URL to add to Placid. The documentation for the Graph API is here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api

Comment: @KellyCook: This information is excellent! I highly recommend posting it as an official answer instead of a comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you would need to create an app for your Facebook page. You are also going to need a Facebook developer account: [developers.facebook.com](https://developers.facebook.com). Once your app is created and you have a Facebook developer account, I would recommend starting with the Facebook open graph explorer: [developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer). With the explorer, you can build/debug your URL to add to Placid. The documentation for the Graph API is here: [developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api)

Comment: Thank you Kelly. I'm making my way through the process now. What would the Placid URL look like? I'm not sure what I'm looking for.

Comment: To elaborate more: I have an access token created for the page, I have my graph API fields picked out - now I just need (I think) the URL and I don't know where that is.

Answer (score 1):

The URL you are probably looking for  in this specific case is in here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.8/page/feed

you want graph.facebook.com/pageid/feed

```
If the url of your facebook page is:
facebook.com/mypage

your graph request for this case is:
graph.facebook.com/mypage/feed
```

The graph API is great, but its very extensive.